# Connect via ssh with a single .bat script to multiple Adresses

Tags: batch-file, ssh

I have a environment of 27 Mikrotik Routers and I want to add a user on each one with same credentials.

Normally I had to connect on every Router and click through the GUI to add the user, but now I found a way to use SSH connection via cmd.

I wrote this - which connects on a single Router and performs the Add-User process

```
ssh admin@10.1.2.3 -password "Passw0rd!" "user add name=customer-support password=#F0ry0u! group=full"
```

But now I want to make a script which maybe reads in a csv file with the ip adresses of all the routers I want to perform the change on and connect on each Router to execute the command.
Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Since [SSH is available for MikroTik](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:System/SSH_client) router, you can indeed read their addresses from a file.

For example, use bash (which you can execute even on Windows through WSL/WSL2 or Git for Windows which includes a [MinGW bash](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

See for example "[Bash Read Comma Separated CSV File on Linux / Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-read-comma-separated-cvsfile/)", here adapted to your case

```
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: Read Comma Separated CSV File
# Author: Vivek Gite under GPL v2.0+
# ------------------------------------------
INPUT=data.cvs
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read maddress
do
    echo "Address : $maddress"
    # do your SSH call here
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

But if you really need a bat script, see for instance "[Help in writing a batch script to parse CSV file and output a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477991/6309)".